# Communicating with Nexus-4 using libusb in firmware update mode

Tags: android, linux, libusb-1.0, android-firmware

I am trying to develop a simple program to communicate with the Nexus-4 bootloader in firmware update mode. 
Nexus -4 has three usb interfaces. Interface-1 has two 2 endpoints - 2 and 131.

I wrote a program to write the command, get-device-info, through endpoint 2 and listen at endpoint 131 for the reply. 
(I tried all permutations of interfaces and endpoints!).

The program successfully writes the command to the device but nothing is read from the device.

Command format: Flag(0x7e): CMD: Data (variable length): CRC-16: Flag(0x7e)

Get-device-info-command: 0x7e 0x00 0x78 0xf0 0x7e

The following is the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

#define INTERFACE 1
#define EP_OUT 2
#define EP_IN 131

int main() {

        libusb_device **devs; // retrieve a list of devices
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle; // device handler
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL; //a libusb session

    int r, r2, i; 
    ssize_t cnt; //holding number of devices in list

    unsigned char data[30],read_data[512]; //data to write

    data[0]=0x7e;data[1]=0x00;data[2]=0x78;data[3]=0xf0;data[4]=0x7e; // get-device-info command in HLDC format

    int actual,read_actual; 

    r = libusb_init(&ctx); 

    if(r < 0) {
        printf("Init Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    libusb_set_debug(ctx, 3); 

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs); //get the list of devices

    if(cnt < 0) {
        printf("Get Device Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d Devices in list\n",(int)cnt);

    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, 4100, 25371); //these are vendorID and productID I found for Nexus-4 firmware update

    if(dev_handle == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open device\n");
    else
        printf("Device opened\n");

    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 0); //free the device list


    if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(dev_handle, INTERFACE) == 1) { //find out if kernel driver is attached
        printf("Kernel Driver Active\n");
        if(libusb_detach_kernel_driver(dev_handle, INTERFACE) == 0) //detach it
            printf("Kernel Driver Detached!\n");
    }

    r = libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, INTERFACE); //claim interface 1 Nexus-5/4 FUM
    if(r < 0) {
        printf("Cannot Claim Interface\n");
        printf("%s\n",libusb_error_name(r));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Claimed Interface\n");

    printf("Data to be send -> %s\n",data); //just to see the data that we are writing 
    printf("Writing Data...\n");

    r = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, (EP_OUT | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), data, 5, &actual, 0); 

    if(r == 0 && actual == 5){ //we wrote successfully 5 bytes to the device
        printf("Writing Successful!\n");

        printf("Waiting to read from device!\n");
        r2 = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, (EP_IN | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), read_data, 512, &read_actual, 5000); 

        if (r2 >=0){
            if (read_actual > 0){
                printf("Data received by bulk transfer\n");

                printf("Data is ");
                for (i=0; i<read_actual; i++)
                    printf("%x ",read_data[i]);
                printf("\n");
            }
            else{
                printf(stderr, "No data received in bulk transfer (%d)\n", r2);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else{   
            fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data via bulk transfer %d\n", r2);
            return r2;                                                      
        }
    }
    else
        printf("Write Error\n");

    r = libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, INTERFACE); //release the claimed interface
    if(r!=0) {
        printf("Cannot Release Interface\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Released Interface\n");

    libusb_close(dev_handle); 
    libusb_exit(ctx); 

    return 0;
}
```

The program is able to send the command successfully to the phone but it is not able to receive any response from the phone. When I run the program, I get the following output:

---

10 Devices in list

Device opened

Kernel Driver Active

Kernel Driver Detached!

Claimed Interface

Data to be send -> ~

Writing Data...

Writing Successful!

Waiting to read from device!

Error receiving data via bulk transfer -7

---

I am not sure the reason for not getting a response is because of the wrong command structure or because of the implementation of the program?

Comment: Any pointers on the same? I am facing the same issue.